# Running commands as linux user on java spring

Tags: linux, spring-boot, unix, ssh, acl

I was thinking of using ssh on java spring boot. But every research I've done on the internet says it's not safe. But I need it to use the features of linux users. Do you think it makes sense to use SSH? Or is there an alternative way to do this?

**What I want to?**
I want to use Unix ACL with users. So I can manage file/folder permissions by user like this

[image]

guitarpoet said it's bad idea to do this :

[Executing commands over SSH using Java Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987772/executing-commands-over-ssh-using-java-spring)

Comment: Do you mean using SSH to set the permissions on a file or folder? You can do that with chown, although that needs root permissions to run so you might need some way to trigger an elevated process to do that for you. Or do you mean to change the current request's run-as user to limit which files it can access? Ditto might need root permissions to su, but I doubt that would play well with a multi-threaded web server anyway. So I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: If you do want to do something in a different process on the same host though it'd make more sense to su rather than ssh.

Comment: I want to get file/folder permissions and also change permissons. So I need to user password or rsa key. You can think like this: We have so many users and users files are private and dynamic. So specific users can access their files.  @Rup

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details or clarification. To me it is still not clear what you want to do, even with your comment. Maybe you can add a few examples of what you want to achieve,

Comment: Even with the picture it still not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to implement a web application for different users? What's the purpose of the application? How do you want to authenticate the users? Will the users supply a password or public key for accessing the files? Will the files also be accessed by other means? Please add links to the sources that say "it's not safe". What does "safe" mean to you? Safe against what kind of threat? ... Your question might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: This is a web file manager interface on each user's home directories on a large shared system? And you want to make sure that each user has access to exactly the same things they'd have if logged in to a shell?

Comment: Yes this is a web file manager. Users are using to login with ssh and they can update their own file permission for file sharing with each other @Rup

Comment: Why don't your users use an SFTP client?  They will get the usual folders - files interface.  Or use something like https://sprut.io/en/ or https://tinyfilemanager.github.io/ or ... ?

Comment: Actually I already designed a file manager on a browser. So I don't want to use ready source like you have prefer file manager. Also I already connecting with SSH and using SFTP for file processes @Nic3500